# If span class contains certain text

Tags: html, xpath

I have this html here

```
<span id="js_11" class="timestampContent">December 16, 2013</span>
```

I want to check if the span class contains the value 2013. How should i write the xpath?

These are what i have tried so far and they are either invalid or has no matching nodes according to Firepath.

```
//span[@class='timestampContent']//span[contains(text(), '2013')]
//class[contains(text(), '2013')]
//@class="timestampContent" //span[contains(text(), '2013')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply combine the 2 conditional check using `and` operator, like so :

```
//span[@class='timestampContent' and contains(text(), '2013')]
```